# What is better way to validating incoming request out of controller in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7, laravel-validation

The standard way to validating incoming requests in Laravel is something like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Show the form to create a new blog post.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('post.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a new blog post.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
            'body' => 'required',
        ]);

        // The blog post is valid...
    }
}
```

There’s nothing wrong with validating requests in controllers, But how could I write the validation logic out of the controller to keep it clean and not break Single Responsibility Principle?

Comment: use validation by js

Comment: You can use `middlewares` and specify the common rules there, then assign that `middleware` in the routes you want to apply the validation

Comment: @MD.JubairMizan validation by js does not guaranteed that the request is valid in server side!

Comment: @GummaMocciaro How this middleware should work? How could I define validation rules of each route?

Comment: @RohamRafii, `middlewares` are mostly used to validate a request, basically is something that occurs before the controller is invoked, i suggest to use the `form request` solution, but if you want to know more about `middlewares`, you can check https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/middleware

Comment: @GummaMocciaro Is there a standard clean way to use middleware for validating requests?

Comment: `middlewares` are commonly used to allow an HTTP request, for example in `APIs` you may want to allow some routes only if a token is present in the request, or maybe if a specific `auth` param is present, is not used to validate forms or custom requests

Answer (score 4):

You could make your own form Request.

1. First create a request with `php artisan make:request StorePostRequest`
2. Create your own rule in this class like:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
        'body' => 'required',
    ];
}
```

3. Update your controller function

```
 public function store(StorePostRequest $request)
    {

        // do something
    }
```

For more info:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#creating-form-requests

Answer (score 3):

Use the form requests provided by Laravel:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#creating-form-requests

and make sure your controller uses the `ValidatesRequests` trait.

Form requests are validated before the controller actions are executed and contain validation rules and authorization logics.